# Java bean instantiation method

Tags: java, design-patterns, javabeans

This is a question about code structure rather than syntax. I'm building a program with multiple Java bean objects. Java beans have a no parameters constructor. Normally when I want a bean I do

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
bean.setPropertyOne("Foo");
bean.setPropertyTwo("Bar");
```

If I've got 12 bean types, and I'm continually rewriting versions of the above each time I need a new bean, that seems like a lot of potential redundancy. It would make more sense to have a constructor that takes parameters, but this goes against the Java Bean design pattern. I'm considering that it might make sense to create a distinct data class which has all the Bean creation methods for all the different beans and then get the required bean via that class each time I need it. This would keep the code modular. I could then access the bean as follows:

```
MyBean bean = myBeanCreationUtility.makeMyBean("Foo", "bar");
```

What kind of design pattern is commonly used for structing this when your writing software?

Comment: Factory pattern

Comment: Can't you just use HashMap<String, String>? Or you can have a look at Kotlin, which simplifies POJOs quite a bit: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: You can create *both* a constructor without parameters (leaving it empty) *and* a constructor with parameters.

Comment: @Héctor is the Factory method what I'm describing with the bridging dataclass? I've had a quick look on line and it sounds like it

Comment: @Pino I thought part of the interface requirements for a Java bean as opposed to a POJO was that it didn't have parameters in its constructor? https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/need-know-javabeans/

Comment: @JayBlack yes, you can check here the creational patterns and see which one adapts better your use case https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/

Comment: @Héctor Thanks! that's a really useful resource. bookmarked! If you add an answer rather than a comment I can tick it.

Comment: @JayBlack read better that page: it says, like me, "if the class has at least one constructor that accepts one or more parameters, it must also have a constructor that has no parameters to qualify as a JavaBean".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Factory pattern is what you are looking for. Check [this website](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/) that contains several design patterns, including creational ones, like Factory Method or Abstract Factory.

Comment: Neither Factory Method nor Abstract Factory have any relation to instantiating Java Beans. The Builder pattern is an option though.

Comment: Yes, they do, because are creational pattern and builder, too. One thing doesn't rule out the other.

Comment: Java Beans rule out the GoF factory patterns.